# remove tuples with only one item -- python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples and some of the tuples only have one item in it. How do I remove tuples with only one item from the list? I want to keep tuples with two items in it.

The tuples I have contain a string, and then an integer after it

```
list = ((['text'],1),(['text'],2),((3,))
```

Comment: I don't see a `list` here, also naming your variable `list` will shadow the built-in type `list` also are you stating that your desired output is to remove the last entry here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may suggest:

```
filtered_list = [tup for tup in list if len(tup) == 2]
```

You can also check if tuple length is higher than one or anything else...

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if len(x) > 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a list with squared brackets instead of parentheses, otherwise you'd create a tuple.

Also please don't call your variables like built-in names as EdChum suggested.

The solution here is to filter your list:

```
l=[(1,2),(3,),(4,5)]
filter(lambda x: len(x)!=1, l)
```

Comment: Don't forget to assign your result, otherwise it is lost.

Comment: Don't use `filter` if you need to use a `lambda` to use it. The behavior is inconsistent between Py2 and Py3, and when you need to use a `lambda`, it's typically slower and more verbose. Use list comprehension (aka listcomp), `[x for x in l if len(x) != 1]`, or generator expression (aka genexpr), `(x for x in l if len(x) != 1)` instead, and get consistent, faster (and according to Guido, more Pythonic) behavior on Py2 and Py3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that to rebuild a new tuple with tuple that have a length greater than 1.

```
new_list = tuple(item for item in your_list if len(item) > 1)
```